# Regular expression for numeric range

Tags: regex

Looking for a regular expression to cover a number range. More specifically, consider a numeric format:

```
NN-NN
```

where N is a number. So examples are:

```
04-11
07-12
06-06
```

I want to be able to specify a range. For example, anything between:

`01-27`  and `02-03`

When I say range, it is as if the `-` is not there. So the range:
the range `01-27` to  `02-03`

would cover:
`01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31` and `02-01`

I want the regular expression so that I can plug in values for the range very easily.  Any ideas?

Comment: what regexp-flavor are you using? See this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) for insiration

Comment: So these are dates? Because otherwise, what's the explanation for `01-32` not being included? You cannot (or should not) do this completely with regex alone.

Comment: Are these dates? If so you do not want to validate them using regex. Instead use the date lib/tools in your language.

Comment: what exactly is it that you want the regex to match ? Provide input + expected output, so that we know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: language is bash script run in windows using cygwin.  output is the list of files names that match the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Validating dates is not where regexes strengths are.

for example, how would you validate February regarding leap years.

The solution is to use the available date API's in your language

Comment: Not trying to validate dates. The dates are in the file name. I just want to pick files that are after one date and before another date.

Comment: Capture the two numbers in regex groups then, convert the discovered number strings to numerical types and compare the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`'0[12]-[0-3][1-9]'` would match all of the required dates, however, it would also match dates like 01-03. If you want to match exactly and only the dates in that range, you'll need to do something a little more advanced.

Here's an easily configurable example in Python:

```
from calendar import monthrange
import re

startdate = (1,27)
enddate = (2,3)

d = startdate
dateList = []

while d != enddate:
    (month, day) = d
    dateList += ['%02i-%02i' % (month, day)]
    daysInMonth = monthrange(2011,month)[1] # took a random non-leap year
                            # but you might want to take the current year
    day += 1
    if day > daysInMonth:
        day = 1
        month+=1
        if month > 12:
            month = 1
    d = (month,day)

dateRegex = '|'.join(dateList)

testDates = ['01-28', '01-29', '01-30', '01-31', '02-01',
              '04-11', '07-12', '06-06']

isMatch = [re.match(dateRegex,x)!=None for x in testDates]

for i, testDate in enumerate(testDates):
    print testDate, isMatch[i]
```

`dateRegex` looks like this:

```
'01-27|01-28|01-29|01-30|01-31|02-01|02-02'
```

And the output is:

```
01-28 True
01-29 True
01-30 True
01-31 True
02-01 True
04-11 False
07-12 False
06-06 False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear for me, and you didn't mention language as well, but in PHP it looks like this:

```
if (preg_match('~\d{2}-\d{2}~', $input, $matches) {
 // do something here
}
```

Do you have any use case so we can adjust code to your needs?